# Laravel one to many grab only one object from the collection

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many

I have two models, a `Phrase` model and a `Translations` model. One `phrase` can have many `translations`. In my `phrase` model I have the following relation:

```
public function translations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Translation::class);
}
```

On one of my pages I want to show only the translations based on a certain language. For example, there are 10 phrases I want to show, including their translations. I have 5 translations for each phrase in the database. Using a `whereHas` I return only the 10 phrases including their respective translations. So far so good. My `whereHas`:

```
$phrases = Phrase::with('translations')->whereHas('translations', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('lang', 'en');
})->get();
```

This returns a collection of phrases with each one relation, to the translated version. On my show page I cannot simply do this:

```
@foreach($phrases as $phrase)
    {{ $phrase->name }} // The actual Phrase name
    {{ $phrase->translation->name }} // The translated version of the phrase
@endforeach
```

First of all, because the relation `translation` does not exist here: `$phrase->translation`, and second of all, the `translations` are a collection as well.

So my question is, if you understand what I am trying to achieve, is something like the foreach I posted possible in some simple way?

PS. I know I could simply convert my original collection to an array but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you using a seperate `hasOne` relation to fetch one translation from your database which you can constrain further in your query.

**`Phrase` model**

```
class Phrase
{
    public function translation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Translation::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$phrases = Phrase::with([
    'translation' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('lang', 'en');
    },
])->get();
```

This should yield the expected result but is untested.

Comment: This did exactly the trick, nice one, didn't think about this, thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped you. We're using this trick a lot in our app. You can even use [query builder methods](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) with the relation and be still able to eager-load it. If your name your relation methods well it can remove a bit of congitive load and repeating code lines from your code as well.

Comment: Sounds good, I learn as I go, I sometimes figure stuff out myself and sometimes I know the solution can be as easy as you posted, but very helpful so, great stuff

Comment: That's why I like Laravel. It's easy to understand for beginners and even if you work with it for years you will always find something new. I often encurage my team to do source-code diving, where they can roam free in the sources of Laravel and figure out things on their own or even find new, undocumented things. Really fun!